# How do I solve this? java.io.IOException: Stream Closed

Tags: java, fileinputstream

Please help me. I'm working with my stop word code, using **FileInputStream** but I got an error that says **java.io.IOException: Stream Closed**. I was following a tutorial in YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckQUlI7x7hI and his code run without error.

Here is the code:

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class DataCleaning {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList sw = new ArrayList<>();

        try{
            FileInputStream x = new FileInputStream("/Users/Dan/Desktop/DATA/stopwords.txt");

            byte b[] = new byte[x.available()];
            x.read(b);
                x.close();

                String data[] = new String(b).split("\n");

            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                sw.add(data[i].trim());
            }
             FileInputStream xx = new FileInputStream("/Users/Dan/Desktop/DATA/cleandata.txt");

            byte bb[] = new byte[x.available()];
            xx.read(bb);
                xx.close();

                String dataa[] = new String(bb).split("\n");



                for(int i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++)

            {
                String file = "";
                String s[] = dataa[i].split("\\s");
                for(int j = 0; j < s.length; i++)
                {
                    if(sw.contains(s[j].trim().toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        file=file + s[j] + " ";
                    }

                }
                System.err.println(file + "\n");
            }

        } catch(Exception a){
            a.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

and this is the error when i run the code:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
at java.io.FileInputStream.available(Native Method)
at datacleaning.DataCleaning.main(DataCleaning.java:28)
```

Comment: How is your code different from his code? How is your data different from his data?

Comment: Hint: `x.available()` <-- is `x` open at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must fix your `bb` initialization:

```
byte bb[] = new byte[xx.available()];
```

`xx.available()` instead of `x.available()`